# Batch file renaming with a number with fitting 00 prefix

Tags: batch-file, renaming

So I have lots of mp3 files on my windows 10 computer which I want to rename with a fitting zero prefix EG rename "mysong1.mp3" to "mysong001.mp3" this batch file I found works fine until the 10th file:

```
@echo off 
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
set i=0 
for %%a in (*.mp3) do (
    set /a i+=1
    ren "%%a" "mysong00!i!.new" 
)
ren *.new *.mp3
```

after the 9th file I get "mysong0010.mp3", "mysong0011.mp3" etc and after the 99th file "mysong00100.mp3". What I want is "mysong010.mp3", "mysong100.mp3" etc. I have done some research on if statements and the likes in batch files but I couldn't quite get the hang of it.

So my question is: How can I make it work like I want it to?

I don't want to use some kind of third party program, I want to be able to do this myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a slight change is all you need.

```
@echo off 
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
set i=0 
for %%a in (*.mp3) do (
    set /a i+=1
    set num=00!i!
    ren "%%a" "mysong!num:~-3!.new"
)
ren *.new *.mp3
```

Comment: I was a bit too quick in accepting the answer it seems. Where exactly do I put the num? What it did now was rename the first file it found into "mysong.mp3" and then return countless times "A duplicate file exists or the file cannot be found". I put the "set num=00!i!" after incrementing i and replaced the ren I posted with yours.

Comment: that's exactly how I had it. Still gives me the same error.

Comment: @Arrrow, that was my bad.  Most of this stuff I write on my phone off the top of my head. Sometimes a syntax error creeps in. Fixed the error.